# Two-letter country code not displaying

Tags: indicator, ibus

I've had kubuntu for about a year, and I decided to download the ubuntu desktop yesterday. However, I have multiple keyboards installed, and the two-letter keyboard layout icon does not show up when I log into ubuntu. It shows up before I log in, but after I log in, there is a box with a crossed-out circle in it.

The only icon that does show up is for a Japanese keyboard layout that I downloaded (anthy). However, none of the others (English, Greek, Russian) show up at all.

Thanks.

New info: I just found out that if I switch the keyboard input method system from IBus to uim in language support, the indicators show up fine, but my Japanese keyboard, anthy (which depends on IBus) no longer works.

Comment: You may need to add them again from System Settings -> Text Entry.

Comment: I already tried that. I even tried adding different keyboards for languages I don't use to see if it was just the ones I had installed. All of them seem to be missing their icons.

Comment: Wonder if the ubuntu-mono package isn't properly installed. You may want to try `sudo apt-get install --reinstall ubuntu-mono`.

Comment: Just did what you said, then readded the keyboards, then restarted the computer. No effect.

Comment: Then it's probably due to some leftover from Kubuntu. I'm out of ideas. Sorry.

Comment: It apparently has something to do with IBus. I put some new info above.

Comment: Maybe you could just switch back to IBus and reboot..